# How to SELECT * INTO [tmp table] without declare table?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

i want use select statement on the a table and inserting result into a temp table variable, but i don't declare temp table with columns and i want use like this:

```
Declare #tmp table;

SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM myTable
```

this should also declare columns and data types for #tmp

Comment: Note that select into isn't a true copy of the table. If you have an identity column, for example, this property is retained, but other table properties and objects (indexes, constraints, triggers, etc.) are not copied.

Comment: Adding note for anyone else who stumbles across this question in the future, the answers provided don't exactly do what the OP was asking. In both cases (`#temp_table` vs `@tableVariable`) you have to specify the column definitions or else it won't work. `SELECT ... INTO` with an empty dataset creates the column definitions matching the table in the `FROM` clause. `SELECT INTO #temp_table` is simpler in that you don't have to define the columns as opposed to `@tableVariable`.

The best practice is use `#temp_table` for large sets of data and `@tableVariable` for small datasets.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can do this simply without the DECLARE command - which is not valid for #temp tables anyway, only @table variables. Did you try just the following without trying to define #tmp first:

```
SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM myTable;
```

Comment: So is your question how to create a #temp table without creating an entry in tempdb.sys.tables? Why do you care? Anyway you can't create a #temp table (or a @table variable) without generating a row in tempdb.sys.tables, sorry.

Comment: ohhh, yes. thanks Aaron. i decide drop temp table by manually

Comment: Don't forget to delete temp table -> drop table #temp at the end

Comment: @user1412699 Why would you do either of those things? ([Please read this post on temp object caching](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-performance/sql-server-temporary-object-caching).)

Answer (score 44):

With data:

```
select *
into #tmp
from myTable
```

No data:

```
select *
into #tmp
from myTable
where 0=1
```

BTW, you can **not** do this with table variables.

```
select *
into @tmp
from myTable
```

Table variables need to be declared with the columns.

Comment: @Aaron - And you got one from me for being first with the correct answer :)

Comment: Even though I only beat you by about 3 seconds? :-)